# Moving constants around during separation of variables

Tags: integration, initial-value-problems

Say you are given a simple differential equation $dy/dx=k*f(x)*g(y)$ where $k$ is a constant, $f(x)$ is some function of $x$, and $g(y)$ is some function of $y$. Am I allowed to move the constant $k$ to the other side of the equation while applying separation of variables such that the equation becomes $dy/(k*g(y))=f(x)dx$ and then integrate each side with respect to the corresponding variable? I am asking this because I did something like this on a math competition today and got the wrong answer as a result, and when I kept k on its original side, I got the right answer. Keep in mind the problem was an initial value problem, so that may have an effect, but I'm not sure. So I am allowed to move constants during separation of variables, and why or why not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer should not depend on which side the constant is. There must have been some other issue

Comment: YuriyS  is correct. If you tell us the question and your solution we might be able to explain your error.

Comment: i think i realized my mistake. after integrating, i got some equation and i flipped it around a little because i was trying to get $y$ as a numerator but when i did the multiplication to both sides, i neglected to multiply the constant of integration $C$ by $y$ as well. would that have made me get the wrong answer?

Comment: ok i just tried the question again and this time when i multiplied both sides by $y$, i also multiplied $C$ by $y$. after doing that, i got a different $C$ from the one you would have gotten if you left the constant on its original side, but i got the right answer. sorry for wasting your time on my careless mistake. i initially didn't multiply $C$ by $y$ because i instinctively thought that multiplying $C$ by anything just made it the same thing, simply a constant. but then i realized that $y$ is a variable, not a constant, so it would not simply be a constant anymore.